# change date format of jQuery textbox

Tags: jquery, css, date, datetime

I want to change the date format of my `input` box.

My current date format is `yyyy-MM-dd`. I want to change the format to `dd-MM-yyyy`

I tried like this

```
<input id="date" type="text" data-beatpicker="true" data-beatpicker-module="clear" dateformat="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
```

and this

```
<script>
    $(document.ready){
        $('#date').beatpicker{
        format:'dd-MM-yyyy';
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="date" type="text" data-beatpicker="true" data-beatpicker-module="clear"/>
```

but I am unable to find a way to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code:

```
<input type="text" data-beatpicker="true" data-beatpicker-position="['right','*']" data-beatpicker-format="['DD','MM','YYYY'],separator:'-'"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one. because default separator is "/" so you have to specify the "-" live specified in bellow example.

```
<script>
    $(document.ready){
        $('#date').beatpicker{
          separator: "-",
          format: ["DD" , "MM" , "YYYY"]
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: have to followed this doc ? http://act1gmr.github.io/BeatPicker/docs.html#options/dateFormat

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#datepicker_id").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
)};
```

// It will set you date format to dd-mm-yy of datepicker

Answer (score 0):

You might try this including the jQuery UI.

```
<input id="date" type="text" data-beatpicker="true" data-beatpicker-module="clear" />

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shishirmax/91L4es6h/1/)